# How to get image url directly in django queryset

Tags: django, django-views

I have a filefield where images are present,

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    display_picture = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True) # #In Use
```

this field is in use so I can not make any model changes. Now this model is connected to another model PriceList. Now previously I was making two db query with one to MyModel and another to PriceList. But right now as they are connected, i want to do this in a single query.

so my query looks something like this
( I am accessing the MyModel through PriceList so I am making a query over PriceList, as they are connected through a `inf` field )

```
all_info_with_price_list.values('inf__display_picture', # I can do this  
                                'inf__display_picture__url' # but not this
)
```

How can I get the url in the query itself? just doing `inf__display_picture` gives me the complete filename.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is a property, not a value in the database (FileField code) which is why you can't get to it from values(). You'd have to get the URL value separately. For example:

```
file_url_tuple_list = list(map(lambda x:(x.info.display_picture.id,
                                         x.info.display_picture.url),
                               list(all_info_with_price_list)))
```